# Wildcard usage for string variables

Tags: stata

Pretty straight-forward question. Can you use wildcard functions for strings in Stata? I haven't been able to find a suitable workaround.

Here's the code I am trying to use:

```
gen newvar= "output" if reg_id == "input*"
```

I have different values of input, i.e. `input12`, `input18`, `input28292`, etc. The wildcard selection does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work as you want. So far as Stata is concerned here, `"*"` is a literal character you are looking for and won't find.

Wildcard syntax like this applies when a variable list is expected, i.e. it can apply to variable names, but to use it with string values you need a dedicated function.

In your example, all cases begin with the string `input`, so this would work:

```
gen newvar = "output" if substr(reg_id, 1, 5) == "input"
```

Stata also supports pattern matching and regular expressions.

```
gen newvar = "output" if strmatch(reg_id, "input*")
```

is in fact the simplest way to get what you ask.

All documented:

```
help string functions
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:

```
gen newvar = "output" if strmatch(reg_id, "input*")
```

see `help strmatch` for usage.

Note also that you can use `regexm` in place of `strmatch`.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept whichever answer you felt addressed the issue. Personally, Nicks answer offers an explanation and is therefore more complete.

Comment: Conversely, encourage the up and coming new generation!